# How can I analyze an executable made for ARM (32 bit) on my x86_64 machine, specifically using Valgrind?

Tags: arm, x86-64, cross-compiling, emulation, valgrind

I have been given an executable compiled for ARM (32 bit) and have to use Valgrind to analyze it. However, my machine is x86_64 and Valgrind is by default only installing tools for x86_64. Also, I don't have access to the source code so I cannot just recompile an executable for my machine and analyze that. Is there any way I can specify options in Valgrind so that it will let me analyze the ARM executable (since I know Valgrind supports analyzing ARM)?

I created an ARM64 VM on Azure and installed Valgrind on there in hopes of it installing corresponding ARM tools. However, it only installed tools for ARM64 and not for ARM 32-bit and did not let me analyze the executable. I tried finding an ARM 32-bit VM but could not find one.